# Two Current Carrying Loops: Multiple Choice Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

I'm studying some simple multiple choice questions from an old test in electrostatics and I have some trouble intuitively grasping this question. I hope someone can explain the solution!

Two current carrying loops are in the xy-plane centred in the origin and the big loop is always fixed. What happens to the equilibrium position of the small loop if the directions of the currents are

1. going in the same direction?
2. going in the opposite direction?

[image]

The possible answers are

a) stable

b) stable if it is only allowed to move in the xy-direction

c) stable if it is only allowed to move in the z-direction

d) unstable

When I tried to solve this I answered 1a and 2c, but the correct answers are 1c and 2b! I used the right hand rule to see where the forces are and for question 1 they are pointing out from the small loop in the xy-direction, which really would make the small loop stable due to the symmetry! The second question I really don't understand. How could we get any forces in the z-direction since the magnetic field is in this direction and force have to be perpendicular? Can someone please help me to understand the solution to this problem?

Comment: You are completely right. The provided answers are wrong. I leave to you elaborate a bit more your analysis and answer your own question, which you have correctly understood. You will earn a badge for this :)

Comment: Two parallel wires carrying current in the same direction will attract each other, due to the magnetic fields that each wire generates.  Two parallel wires carrying currents that are in opposite directions repel each other, again due to the magnet fields that each wire generates.  Is that enough information to make sense of the answers that you posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I used the right hand rule to see where the forces are and for
>   question 1 they are pointing out from the small loop in the
>   xy-direction, which really would make the small loop stable due to the
>   symmetry!

It's true that the force on an inner current element due to the magnetic field of the outer loop is outward.  But the [magnetic field of the outer current loop](http://www.wiley.com/college/halliday/0470469080/simulations/sim37/sim37.html) is not uniform with the field stronger nearer the loop.

Perturb the inner current loop in the $+y$ direction such that the 'top' of the inner loop is closer to the outer loop and the 'bottom' of the inner loop is farther from the outer loop.

The $+y$ magnetic force on the 'top' inner current element is now stronger while the $-y$ magnetic force on the 'bottom' inner current element is now weaker.

Thus, the net magnetic force is in the direction of the perturbation; the inner current loop is not stable against a perturbation in the $xy$ plane when the currents circulate in the same direction.

---

> The second question I really don't understand. How could we get any
>   forces in the z-direction since the magnetic field is in this
>   direction and force have to be perpendicular?

The magnetic field of the outer current loop is in the $z$ direction *only* in the $xy$ plane or on the $z$ axis; out the $xy$ plane and off the $z$ axis, the magnetic field has non-zero $x$ and/or $y$ components.

If the inner current loop is perturbed up the $z$ axis, there is a downward directed component of the magnetic force on any inner current element (remember, the magnetic force is directed *towards* the outer loop).  Thus, the net magnetic force is in the opposite direction to the perturbation; the inner current loop is stable against a perturbation in the $z$ direction when the currents circulate in the same direction.

So, the correct answer for the case that the currents circulate in the same direction is (c).

Now, apply the above to the case that the currents circulate in opposite directions and see that the answer is ...